# How to coerce column to be numeric with merged values

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I have a large data set in which one of the columns is monetary, however the values in that column have different patterns, so that when I try to apply `as.numeric` some values become missings.

Specifically, I have:

```
structure(list(test = c("200.09", "409.12", "00456,12", "00456,15"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

when I apply `as.numeric`, I get a new column like:

```
structure(list(test = c("200.09", "409.12", "00456,12", "00456,15"
), test_numeric = c(200.09, 409.12, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, I would like to obtain:

```
structure(list(test = c("200.09", "409.12", "00456,12", "00456,15"
), test_numeric = c(200.09, 409.12, 456.12, 456.15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `,` is considered to be character and changes the whole column to type `character`.  We can replace with `.` and convert.

```
df1$test_numeric <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", df1$test))
```

Other option is while reading the data, specify the `dec = ','`.  With `read.table/read.csv` the default option is `dec = '.'`, whereas in `read.delim2/read.csv2`, it is `dec =','`